# Meaning of [Z] in format + string in Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I am wondering what this does:

```
newM = moment("2015-08-11T13:00:00.000000Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSS[Z]", true)
```

Specifically - the [Z] in the format string.

I am using a library (react-bootstrap-datetimepicker) which uses moment. This library (React component) takes a parameter 'format' which is used as the second parameter to moment

I can't see what the [Z] is doing. But I have to do this rather than just 'Z' to get the result I want when I format the moment object for display with this string: newM.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSZ').

EDIT:

to be clear: I understand that 'Z' will cause the datetime passed to be treated as UTC, as per the docs. But what is the significance of the square brackets - which are not in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Z` does not cause the time to be treated as UTC when used in the format. It matches a timezone specifier:

```
Format: Z ZZ
Example: +12:00
Description: Offset from UTC as +-HH:mm, +-HHmm, or Z
```

And under the documentation for `format`:

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in
>   square brackets.

By specifying `Z` in brackets, you are matching a literal `Z`, and thus the timezone is left at moment's default, which is the local timezone.

> Unless you specify a time zone offset, parsing a string will create a
>   date in the current time zone.

If your time is really in UTC, this is probably not desired behavior. If you want to parse it as UTC but display it in local time, use `Z` and then call `local()` on the resulting `moment` object, so most likely what you want is:

```
// Parse with timezone specifier (which is UTC here) but convert to local time
newM = moment("2015-08-11T13:00:00.000000Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ", true).local();
```

Comment: Actually, when you parse a date with an offset using the default 'moment' function, it will automatically be converted from that offset to local. See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/

Comment: Yes, but this is not the default `moment` function, this is the overload which takes a strict format. My first quote is straight from the `String + Format` documentation, while your link refers to the `String` version.

Comment: Strict mode does not affect that behavior. It only affects separator matching. Go to momentjs.com and run moment("2015-08-11T13:00:00.000000Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ", true).format() in the console. You will see that I am correct.

Comment: Docs are definitely unclear where you are looking. Created https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/issues/300 and will fix it later.

Comment: I read this example in the docs: "moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC" as saying that the Z in the format string causes the date to be read as UTC. However; the point is, as the docs make clear if you read the line above this - that it is the +0000 which is causing the date to be parsed as UTC. The Z is matching the +0000. Thanks Dark Falcon.

Comment: (Can't seem to edit my previous comment). The line above the example I quoted says ""Unless you specify a time zone offset, parsing a string will create a date in the current time zone." The implication is that the time zone offset, or Z, in the given time is causing the date to be parsed as UTC.The Z in the format string is matching that. I inspected the created moment object and it has isUTC = true.

Comment: `isUTC` doesn't indicate the timezone of a parsed date. It indicates whether the date will be formatted in UTC. https://jsfiddle.net/g6rf1by8/1/

Comment: That's helpful to know.

Answer (score 22):

For everyone who cares about consistency due to the missing `Z` at the end - try to add `[Z]` to your format.

*Example:* `.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]')` so the result is: `2019-11-26T10:39:54Z`

More detailed explanation you can find in this [github issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/213).